# Test class coverage for QuoteLineModel and QuoteLineGroupModel apex class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, developer

need help in test class code coverage for below classes

```
public class QuoteLineModel {
public SBQQ__QuoteLine__c record;
public SBQQ__QuoteLine__c record;
public Boolean amountDiscountProrated;
public Integer parentGroupKey;
public Integer parentItemKey;
public Integer key;
public Boolean upliftable;
public String configurationType;
public String configurationEvent;
public Boolean reconfigurationDisabled;
public Boolean descriptionLocked;
public Boolean productQuantityEditable;
public Decimal productQuantityScale;
public String dimensionType;
public Boolean productHasDimensions;
public Decimal targetCustomerAmount;
public Decimal targetCustomerTotal;
```

}

```
public class QuoteLineGroupModel {
public SBQQ__QuoteLineGroup__c record;
public Decimal netNonSegmentTotal;
public Integer key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a unit test for this class would be to test that you can create an instance of this class. Then you can assert that the variables are what they should be. Your instance variables will be covered.

```
@isTest
static void testQuoteLineModel() {
    Test.startTest();
    QuoteLineModel inst = new QuoteLineModel();
    Test.stopTest();

    // you can do similar asserts for all the class variables...
    System.assertEquals(null, inst.record);
    System.assertEquals(null, inst.amountDiscountProrated);
}
```

Comment: There is no need to unit test these classes. They contain no executable lines. Asserting that assignment statements work or that variables are uninitialized as guaranteed by the platform has no value for proving the correctness of this code.

Comment: Make sense, what would be the good practice to have coverage on this kind of class ?

Comment: You don't get coverage on these classes at all. (You can't!) I've linked several resources above.